# Airflow XComs, processing thousands/millions of files

Tags: airflow

I am trying to use airflow to process thousands/millions of files. To share these files/data between my tasks, I am currently just saving and pulling from a sql server. However, I believe using XComs would be much easier and would allow me to abstract my code more. But, I understand there is a limit to how much data can be shared between tasks using Xcoms. I am confused on whether this limit only pertains to sending big data through one Xcom, or if it also applies to sending lots of data through many Xcoms (each xcom would only contain like 4kb of data). If I send lots of data through many XComs, would this lead to a memory overload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Airflow - Best Practices - Communication](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/best-practices.html#communication) page:

> If possible, use XCom to communicate small messages between tasks and a good way of passing larger data between tasks is to use a remote storage such as S3/HDFS.

> For example, if we have a task that stores processed data in S3 that task can push the S3 path for the output data in Xcom, and the downstream tasks can pull the path from XCom and use it to read the data.

In your case, you are trying to share big amount of data within tasks; so the best practice would be **sharing the paths of the data between those tasks** (even if it is locally saved to your machine) with XCOM.

Something like the code down below can give you an idea.

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from random import uniform
from datetime import datetime

default_args = {
    'owner': 'admin',
    'start_date': datetime(2020, 1, 1)
}

def _save_data(**kwargs):
    path = "directory/data.csv"
    kwargs["task_instance"].xcom_push(key="data_path", value=path)

def _choose_best_model(**kwargs):

    print('Fetch Data Path')

    data_path_to_work_on = kwargs["task_instance"].xcom_pull(
        task_ids="training_model", 
        key="data_path"
    )
    print(f"Deploying data from: {data_path_to_work_on}")

with DAG('test_xcom_data_path',schedule_interval='@daily',default_args=default_args, catchup=False) as dag:

    downloading_data = BashOperator(
    task_id='downloading_data',
    bash_command='sleep 3'
    )

    save_data_task =PythonOperator(
    task_id='save_data_path',
    python_callable=_save_data
    ) 

    choose_model = PythonOperator(
    task_id='choose_model',
    python_callable=_choose_best_model
    )

downloading_data >> save_data_task >> choose_model`
```